# Adding new Component(Button) on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a TODO app.
When i click on a button - it asks for text and puts it in button label, and it must create an empty button that will ask for text when clicked and create another button etc.

Two buttons appear, but when i click on one and input text in it - text appears, but new button is not created. please help

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class TaskButton extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        taskName: "Undefined"
    };
}

addTask = () => {
        var taskText = prompt('What to write ?', "");
        TASKS.push()
        this.setState({
            taskName: taskText
        })
};

render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.addTask}>
         {this.state.taskName}
        </button>
      );
    }
  };


var test = [
<div> <TaskButton> </TaskButton> </div>, 
<div> <TaskButton> </TaskButton> </div>
];

var listItems = test.map((test, index) =>
<li key={index}>{test}</li>
);
class TaskMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {listItems}
            </ul>
        )    
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <TaskMenu />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);

export default TaskMenu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code

```js
class TaskMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tasks: ["undefined"]
    };
    this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this);
  }
  addTask(e){
    var task = prompt('What to write ?', "");
    var index = e.target.getAttribute("data-index");
    this.state.tasks[index] = task;
    this.setState({tasks: +index=== this.state.tasks.length-1 ? [...this.state.tasks, "undefined"]: [...this.state.tasks]});
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.tasks.map((task, i)=><li key={i}> <button onClick={this.addTask} data-index={i}>{task}</button> </li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <TaskMenu />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id ="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```